# Outlook spelling/proofing language / dictionary issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, language

I'm using Office 2010. Every time I try to send an email I get this:
[image]

`Dictionary language: Spanish (International Sort)`

It marks almost all the english words. I need english proofing.
I already set the dictionary like this:
[image]

Also on Review tab -> Language -> Set proofing language... the default is English U.S.:
[image]

What the hack is that? Where on earth shall I do the necessary setting?

Comment: In the first picture, can you change the dictionary used (in dictionary language)?

Comment: Yes I can, but next time it reverts back to Spanish.

Comment: I don't use Outlook so I can't be of much help. However, [this question](http://superuser.com/q/438928/228536) seems very similar to yours; it has a solution that you may try and use.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already tried this as well. An hour of googling was my first action.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found to this problem is to add English as a new language to windows along with your own keyboard selected (to not have wrong characters while writing)

When using Office programs, the proofreader always switch to the language selected in the language bar. If no language bar is present, you have only one language selected on windows and office programs' proofreader switches to this language.

Comment: I have no language bar, and I have only english in windows, and as far as I'm concerned in office too.

Comment: You can also add/modify system languages via `Control Panel` -> `Region & Language` if you've hidden the language bar.